# How do I get rid of abnormalities from Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, percentile, iqr

If I want to remove values that do not exist between -2σ and 2σ, how do I remove outliers using iqr?

I implemented this equation as follows.

```
iqr = df['abc'].percentile(0.75) - df['abc'].percentile(0.25)

cond1 = (df['abc'] > df['abc'].percentile(0.75) + 2 * iqr)
cond2 = (df['abc'] < df['abc'].percentile(0.25) - 2 * iqr)

df[cond1 & cond2]
```

Is this the right way?

Comment: If you're getting the output you expect, then it's right. If not, provide a sample of your `df`, along with your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not right. Your `iqr` is almost never equal to σ. Quartiles and deviations are not the same things.

Fortunately, you can easily compute the standard deviation of a numerical Series using [`Series.std()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.std.html).

```
sigma = df['abc'].std()

cond1 = (df['abc'] > df['abc'].mean() - 2 * sigma)
cond2 = (df['abc'] < df['abc'].mean() + 2 * sigma)

df[cond1 & cond2]
```